# If $N \unlhd A_n$, then elements of order $2$ or $3$ in $N$ imply $N$ contains generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am not assuming we know $A_n$ is simple for this question.

Suppose that $n >4$ and that $N$ is normal in $A_n$. If $p \in N$ is a permuatation that has order either $2$ or $3$, then I want to show $N$ contains either a $3$-cycle or a product of disjoint transpositions.

In either case, we can write $p$ as the product of disjoint $2$-cycles or $3$-cycles, respectively. Then somehow we want to use that $N$ is normal by finding a suitable conjugation of $p$. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: But for $n\geq 5$ isn't $A_n$ simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of order $2$, note that single 2-cycles are not in $A_n$. Given an element like $\alpha=(1\,2)(3\,4)(\cdots)\in N$ where the dots represent a non-negative number of 2-cyles, we als have its conjugate $\beta=(1\,3)(2\,4)(\cdots)\in N$, as well as their product $\alpha\beta=(1\,4)(2\,3)$. As $n>4$, we also have $(1\,5)(2\,3)$ and the product $(1\,5\,4)$.

In the case of order $3$, suppose we have $\alpha=(1\,2\,3)(\cdots)$ where the dots represent a non-negative number of 3-cyles. Then we also have $\beta=(1\,3\,2)(\cdots)$ and also $\alpha^2\beta=(1\,2\,3)$. By conjugation, we also have $(1\,2\,4)$ and the product $(1\,3)(2\,4)$.